# why does import module in same directory gets error

Tags: python-3.x

directory structure

```
test/
    __init__.py
    line.py
    test.py
```

test.py

```
from . import line
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import line
ImportError: cannot import name 'line'
```

I know I can just `import line`. but it may import standard library in python3.

why did this error happen? does python3 support this syntax?

ps: I'm not in interactive console and test directory has already been a package

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can import module with the same name as library utilities directly. However, you could consider putting your modules inside a package, so your directory structure would look like:

```
.
├── main.py
├── package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── line.py
│   ├── test.py
```

Where `__init__.py` might have some setup commands (you can omit this file if you have none) and in `main.py` you can do the following:

```
from package import line
...
```

Within the directory `package` if you'd like to say, import `line.py` in `test.py` you can use the syntax:

```
from . import line
```

Note relative imports (using the `from .` notation) will only work inside the script and not in the interactive console. Running the `test.py` ( if it's using relative imports) directly will also not work, although importing it from `main.py` will work.